# Is $ K(x) $ is not maximal ideal ? yes/no

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the  following is true/false

Given $C((0,1),\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ , for any $x\in (0,1)$, let  $K(x)=\{f\in C(X,\mathbb{R} | f(x)=0\}$.
Then  $K(x)$ is not  maximal ideal

My attempt : i thinks  yes  because for maximal ideal   $x$ must  be  one value  i mean  $f(1/2) = 0$

Is its  true ?

Comment: "yes"  is not an answer to a true/false question.  Do you mean you think it *is maximal*, and hence the answer to the question in the body is *"The statement is false"*?

Comment: Your attempt needs to be clarified. I can't make any sense of "because for maximal ideal $x$ must be one value I mean $f(1/2)=0$"

Comment: Also, if you search for "maximal ideal continuous functions" you can find perhaps a dozen similar questions which already provide answers that answer this question. I seem to recall several times before reminding you to search before asking, but I will do so one last time.

Comment: im confused @rschwieb

Comment: I can tell. But unfortunately your feedback is too cryptic for me to see what your confusion is. I'm not going to guess... so help us out by explaining a bit what you feel is confusing.

Comment: im confused that  what  is difference between   $C((0,1))$ and $C((0,1),R))$ @rschwieb

Comment: @jasmine Unless otherwise stated, they're exactly the same if we're dealing with real functions. Either way, it is the set of *continuous* functions from the unit interval to the reals, with the usual operations of sum and product of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$\phi: C(0,1)\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;\phi(f):= f(x)$$

Then, $\;K(x)=\ker\phi\;$ , so $\;C(0,1)/K(x)\cong\Bbb R\;$ (why?) , so ...